# How to use a Boolean to exit out of a 'for' loop?

Tags: python, list, boolean

I am a beginner in Python, so I apologise in advance if my question is very basic or obvious. I am trying to write a function called `find(my_list, value)` that takes a list, and a value as parameters. The function searches for the value in the list and returns the index at which the first occurrence of the value is found in the list. I want the function to return -1 if the value isn't found in the list.

The catch is that I am unable to use any in-built functions, except for `range()` and `str()`. I also cannot use `quit()` or `exit()` or `break` or `return` statements to exit out of loops.

I am attempting to use a 'for' loop method, as well as a Boolean statement (to control when to stop the loop). I think I am on the right track, but believe there is an issue with my implementation. I am getting the desired output (-1) for when the value is *not* in the list. But, I cannot seem to get the desired output for when the value is in the list. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
    def find(my_list, value):

        index = 0
        valid = False

        if value != my_list:
            found = -1

        for element in my_list:
            if element == value:
                valid = True
                found = index

        else: 
            index += 1

    return found
```

The list:

```
    str_list1 = ['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

The call to the function:

```
    print(list_function.find(str_list1, 'g'))
    print(list_function.find(str_list1, 'z'))
```

Expected output:

```
    3
    -1
```

Comment: Better to raise an exception; that prevents you from naively trying to use `-1` as the list index later if you forget to check the return value.

Comment: Please add the function call you make, the expected and the actual return value

Comment: @jtlz2 Don't fix the indentation of Python code; you fixed the actual problem in doing so.

Comment: Question: in comments under a question one person pointed out that you didn't say whether you can use `len` builtin. In my answer I automatically assumed you can because, well, `range` doesn't make much sense for the lists if you don't have the list length. So can you or can you not use `len` in your solution?

Comment: @h4z3 `len` is fine to use only when accompanied by `range`. If I worded that sensibly :) For example, `range(len(my_list))`

Comment: Question: in comments under a question one person it is no correct place, make a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is off. You *intended* the `else` go belong to the `if` statement, but it's actually bound to the `for` loop, which means `index` is only increment when the loop exits naturally (which is always, because you don't have any other way of exiting the loop (a `break` statement or a `return` statement).

```
def find(my_list, value):
    index = 0
    for element in my_list:
        if element == value:
            return index
        else:
            index += 1

    # If we get here, no match was found
    return -1
```

Note that we don't need `valid`.

A cleaner way to write this is to use `enumerate`, which generates the index for you.

```
def find(my_list, value):
    for index, element in enumerate(my_list):
        if element == value:
            return index

    # If we get here, no match was found
    return -1
```

Update: If you can't break out of the loop early, you do need `valid`, though you still need to keep the index to return separate from the current index. (I'm guessing you can't use `enumerate` either.)

```
def find(my_list, value):
    answer = -1
    index = 0
    for element in my_list:
        if element == value:
            answer = index
        index += 1
    
    return answer
```

This will return the index of the *last* value found, if `value` appears more than once. To return the *first* instance, you'll want to check if `answer` has already been changed from the default of -1.

```
def find(my_list, value):
    answer = -1
    index = 0
    for element my_list:
        if answer == -1 and element == value:
            answer = index
        index += 1
    
    return answer
```

Comment: I did. That's a lame requirement (though it explains the need for `valid`).

Comment: That's going to return a (sub)list of the input beginning with `value`, not the index of the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

I have kept the requirements of **not** using built-in functions and **not** using `break`.

**Edit**: I just read the post again, that you cannot cannot use `return` statements to exit out of loops, so here's another way to do it. I first assumed that the element is not found (-1), then loop through the list while increasing the index, and assign the index if the element is found. Here's the code:

```
def find(my_list, value):
    found = -1
    idx = 0

    for element in my_list:
        if (element == value) and (found == -1) :
            found = idx
        idx += 1

    return found

str_list1 = ['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g']
print(find(str_list1, 'g'))
print(find(str_list1, 'z'))
```

Output:

```
3
-1
```

And if you can accept the use of `.index()` here's a sweet one

```
def find(my_list, value):
    return my_list.index(value) if value in my_list else -1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use `break`, use `while` for a manual for loop.

First let's make if into a correct for loop with index:

```py
        for index in range(len(my_list)):
            element = my_list[index]
            if element == value:
                valid = True
                found = index
                break # I know, it's only for now
```

Now we will go through it manually:

```py
        while index < len(my_list):
            element = my_list[index]
            if element == value:
                valid = True
                found = index
                break
            index += 1
```

Now let's think: how else can we finish the while loop? By having a condition that is false!

Let's move the `if` condition to `while` condition but swapped (we want it to continue while *not equal*):

```py
        while index < len(my_list) and my_list[index] != value:
            index += 1
```

Now, if `index == len(my_list)`, then the element was not found (first part of the condition failed). If it's anything lower, then it's the found index. :)

```py
        while index < len(my_list) and my_list[index] != value:
            index += 1
        return index if index < len(my_list) else -1
```

---

**Edit:** Now I see I shortened it *quite a bit*... To keep more of your code, you can do the `and not valid` as condition and that's probably what you planned from the start!

```py
        while index < len(my_list) and not valid:
            element = my_list[index]
            if element == value:
                valid = True
            index += 1
        return index if valid else -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break` to exit the loop:

```
def find(my_list, value):
    index = 0
    found = -1
    for element in my_list:
        if element == value:
            found = index
            break
        index += 1

return found
```

Instead of counting the index by hand, use `enumerate`:

```
def find(list, value):
    found = -1
    for index, element in enumerate(list):
        if element == value:
            found = index
            break
return found
```

You could use `return` directly inside to loop:

```
def find(list, value):
    for index, element in enumerate(list):
        if element == value:
            return index
return -1
```

or set `index` in a else-Block to for:

```
def find(list, value):
    for index, element in enumerate(list):
        if element == value:
            break
    else:
        index = -1
return index
```

Comment: OP clearly said "I also cannot use (...) break or return statements to exit out of loops."